# Is there a way to include a factor in ggplot that's not in discrete scale limits?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a figure in ggplot2 where I've set the x and y discrete scale limits to be:

`c("10","20","40","80","160","320","640","1280","2560","5120","10240")`

I've converted my data into factors and there are equal spacing between these numbers. However, I have a value of "50" in my ys, which gets dropped by the y discrete limits. Is there a way to keep these limits (i.e. not change the axes) and still plot the 50 (i.e. between the 40 and 80)? Or another way to get equal spacing between these points that does not include setting limits?

Example:

```
data1 <- data.frame(row_number= c(1,2,3), x1=as.factor(c(320,320,640)), y1=as.factor(c(50,160,160)))  

ggplot(data=data1, aes(x=x1, y=y1)) + geom_jitter(width=0.07) +  scale_x_discrete(limits=c("10","20","40","80","160","320","640","1280","2560","5120","10240")) + scale_y_discrete(limits=c("10","20","40","80","160","320","640","1280","2560","5120","10240"))

#Removes (320,50)
```

Comment: Judging from your limits, why not just use a continuous axis with log2 transforms?

Comment: Your data look numeric. Is there a reason why you insist on them being categorical (factor)?

Comment: @edward I've set them as factors so that the numbers on the axes will be equally spaced. If there's a way to keep them equally spaced with numeric data, I'd be happy to change it.

Comment: @teunbrand thank you for the suggestion - could you write how that would work exactly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than keeping discrete variables, you could use log2 transformed x- and y-axes:

```
data2 <- data.frame(
  row_number = c(1, 2, 3),
  x1 = c(320, 320, 640),
  y1 = c(50, 160, 160)
)

breaks <- c(10, 20, 40, 80, 160, 320, 640, 1280, 2560, 5120, 10240)

ggplot(data2, aes(x1, y1)) +
  geom_jitter(width = 0.07) +
  scale_x_continuous(trans = "log2", 
                     breaks = breaks,
                     limits = range(breaks)) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "log2", 
                     breaks = breaks,
                     limits = range(breaks))
```

[image]